# VoiceOver cursor and event handlers in HTML5

Tags: html, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

We have a web application that supports accessibility, special tab ordering of both gui and non-gui (drawn on canvas) elements, etc.
On desktop, we do this with KeyEvent handlers, and works OK on Mac VoiceOver.
But in iPad, swipe left-right only moves the VO cursor, no event handlers are fired (and even tabIndex is ignored)
Is there a way to control VO cursor order and run some code on "focus"?
Thanks.
Laszlo